# How to add memoization to coin change

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am looking at the Leetcode [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/description/) of coin change. I came up with a brute force solution and have some ideas on how to add memoization but looks like I am missing something. Below is my non-memoized function that works.

I was initially thinking about creating a hashmap that stores a tuple of vector, index, and sum and stores a corresponding value of sum against it and I use that in the base cases. But dry running it, it doesn't look right.

Any hints/help much appreciated.

```
void minCoins_Helper2(std::vector<int> coins, int sum, int index, int currCoins, int &min){
    // Base cases
    if(index == coins.size())
        return;
    if(sum < 0)
        return;
    if(sum == 0){
        if(currCoins < min)
            min = currCoins;
        return;
    }
    // Include the coin
    minCoins_Helper2(coins, sum - coins[index], index, currCoins+1, min);
    // Exclude the coin
    minCoins_Helper2(coins, sum, index+1, currCoins, min);
}

int minCoins2(std::vector<int> coins, int sum){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    minCoins_Helper2(coins, sum, 0, 0, min);;
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are missing? What did you try and what did not work when you tried it? (Asking others to write your code for you is off-topic here, as I understand it.)

Comment: Usually Dynamic Programming problems have solutions with overlapping subproblems. Memoization works by recording the solution to a subproblem once the subproblem has been solved, so that the subproblem only has to be solved once. You have made the problem a little tricky in that you don't really break up the problem into subproblems, since you pass the number of used coins down through each recursive call. If you rewrite the helper function to return an optimum value, adding memoization would be very simple.

Comment: @mwistrom - I think I know what you mean. Adding memoization should be straightforward but the way my recursion works above does complicate it. I solved this using bottom-up instead but was still trying to figure out the memoized solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to store vector of coins.

in this problem you just need to have a 2-dimensional array like `dp[i][j]` where `i` is your sum and `j` is your index.

at the end of the `minCoins_helper2` , right after the recursion calls you must store the dp[sum][index] with the minimum answer of two recursion calls.

then at top of the `// include the coins` you should check that if you've computed dp[sum][index] previously then don't call it recursively to save time.

Comment: I think you should elaborate your answer.

Comment: You don't need 2-dimensional array for this problem.